# Change logs in Rails/Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, changelog

I notice that several gems and especially the rails gems all have neatly formatted [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionmailer/CHANGELOG) files.

Are these maintained by the developers themselves or is there some gem/software that manages this automatically with Git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are maintained by the developers, but many use markup languages (such as textile or markdown) to make them look extra pretty.

Comment: thanks - might look into developing a Gem to do this automatically from reading Git commits